# How to change the login and signup urls in devise plugin Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using devise plugin in my new Rails App. My issue is devise plugin has default roots for login and signup

```
/users/sign_in
/users/sign_up
```

I need to change this to

```
/login 
/signup
```

For this I used the following routing

```
 devise_for :users do
   get "login", :to => "devise/sessions#new"
   get "signup", :to => "devise/registrations#new"
 end
```

With this I need to specify 'login_path' and 'signup_path' everywhere in my views where new_user_session_path and new_user_registration_path comes

What I want is a configuration in routes which maps '/login' and '/signup' to  new_user_session_path and new_user_registration_path.

I have seen a post which route /users/sign_in and /users/sign_up to /sign_in and /sign_up using the below shown routing.

```
  devise_for :user, :as => ''
```

I need some routing technique like this which routes /users/sign_in and /users/sign_up to /login and /signup.

Could anyone please help me with this.

UPDATE: I have changed my routes.rb file to

```
  devise_for :users,
         :controllers => { :sessions => 'devise/sessions'},
         :skip => [:sessions] do
       get '/login' => "devise/sessions#new", :as => :new_user_session
       post '/login' => 'devise/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
       get '/signout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
       get '/signup' => 'devise/registrations#new', :as => :new_user_registration
  end
```

But still when I use link_to 'new_user_registration' in my views its not showing as '/signup' in the browser

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here are a little bit more options than you asked but it's clear:

```
  devise_for :users,
             :controllers => { :registrations => "users/registrations",
                               :confirmations => "users/confirmations",
                               :sessions => 'devise/sessions'},
             :skip => [:sessions] do
    get '/signin'   => "devise/sessions#new",       :as => :new_user_session
    post '/signin'  => 'devise/sessions#create',    :as => :user_session
    get '/signout'  => 'devise/sessions#destroy',   :as => :destroy_user_session
    get "/signup"   => "users/registrations#new",   :as => :new_user_registration
  end
```

Even more, with `:registrations => "users/registrations"` we can additionally customize redirects:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    welcome_path # it's not a home path
  end

  def after_update_path_for(resource)
    edit_user_registration_path
  end
end
```

Devise has a good [wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki).

Comment: Thanks dude. My '/signin' in working fine.  But '/signup' is not mapping to 'new_user_registration_path'. I added your code in my routes. Do I need to add anything more.

Comment: It's because I have customized registrations controller as I've shown above. Here is a place `get "/signup" => "users/registrations#new"` where you can change `users` to `devise` and remove `:registrations => "users/registrations"` from `:contorllers` hash.

Comment: devise_for :users,
             :controllers => { :sessions => 'devise/sessions'},
             :skip => [:sessions] do
    get '/login'   => "devise/sessions#new",       :as => :new_user_session
    post '/login'  => 'devise/sessions#create',    :as => :user_session
    get '/signout'  => 'devise/sessions#destroy',  :as => :destroy_user_session
    get "/signup" => "devise/registrations#new",   :as => :new_user_registration
  end   but when I use link_to 'new_user_registration' in my views its not showing as '/signup'

Comment: Hi Voldy can you please take a look at my answer and figure out what the issue is.

Comment: Could you place your current routes (devise part) as update to your question?

Comment: @voldy - My current routes(devise part) is shown in the last part of my question. Could you please take a look at it and suggest me a solution to my issue.

Comment: Why does `get "/signup"   => "users/registrations#new",   :as => :new_user_registration` go under the skip sessions block?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix my issue by using the following code in my routes

```
  devise_for :users,
           :controllers => { :sessions => 'devise/sessions'},
           :skip => [:sessions] do
    get '/login'   => "devise/sessions#new",       :as => :new_user_session
    post '/login'  => 'devise/sessions#create',    :as => :user_session
    get '/signout'  => 'devise/sessions#destroy',   :as => :destroy_user_session
    get "/signup" => "devise/registrations#new", :as => :new_user_registration
  end
```

But still in my views if I use

```
  link_to "Register", new_user_registration_path
```

In my browser its showing as

```
  /user/sign_up   and not as /signup
```

But if I directly type  /signup I will get the registraion page. Is there any mapping I need to do here.

Answer (score 2):

i hope i'm not too late ;)

here is how it works (just paste it in your routes.rb and you good to go):

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions => 'devise/sessions'}, :skip => [:sessions] do
    get 'login' => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
    post 'login' => 'devise/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
    get 'logout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
    get 'register' => 'devise/registrations#new', :as => :new_user_registration
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

edit config/routes.rb

devise_for :users, **path: ''**

```
 devise_for :users, path: '', path_names: { sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout', password: 'secret', confirmation: 'verification', unlock: 'unblock', registration: 'register', sign_up: 'cmon_let_me_in' }

     new_user_session GET    /login(.:format)                         devise/sessions#new
                user_session POST   /login(.:format)                         devise/sessions#create
        destroy_user_session DELETE /logout(.:format)                        devise/sessions#destroy
               user_password POST   /secret(.:format)                        devise/passwords#create
           new_user_password GET    /secret/new(.:format)                    devise/passwords#new
          edit_user_password GET    /secret/edit(.:format)                   devise/passwords#edit
                             PATCH  /secret(.:format)                        devise/passwords#update
                             PUT    /secret(.:format)                        devise/passwords#update
    cancel_user_registration GET    /register/cancel(.:format)               devise/registrations#cancel
           user_registration POST   /register(.:format)                      devise/registrations#create
       new_user_registration GET    /register/cmon_let_me_in(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
      edit_user_registration GET    /register/edit(.:format)                 devise/registrations#edit
                             PATCH  /register(.:format)                      devise/registrations#update
                             PUT    /register(.:format)                      devise/registrations#update
                             DELETE /register(.:format)                      devise/registrations#destroy
```

Answer (score 1):

As this may still be the n°1 result people get when looking for that question, it might be useful to note that there is now a simple way to do that:

```
devise_for :users, path: '', path_names: { sign_in: 'login', sign_up: 'signup'}
```

Reference: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading and understanding your question correctly, you are after 'match'.

```
devise_for :users
match "/login" => "devise/sessions#new"
match "/signup" => "devise/registrations#new"
```

Be sure to have them in the correct order as they are matched based on line numbers in the file.

More can be found at: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Using this routing I need to specify '/login' and '/signup' in my views. So that clicking the link takes to login and registration page. What I was looking is the devise plugin has a link to registration page <%= link_to "signup", new_user_registration_path %> clicking this link the url in the browser must be '/signup'. With devise default routing the link is like '/users/sign_up'. Hope you got my issue. Please help