# Have Devise failed validation remain on same URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm trying to do this [Use custom route upon model validation failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083798/use-custom-route-upon-model-validation-failure) with [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), and I'm not having any luck.

I've got my routes specified like this:

```
# authentication routing
devise_for :users do
  get "/login" => "devise/sessions#new"
  get "/logout" => "devise/sessions#destroy"
  get "/register" => "devise/registrations#new"
end
```

But when validation fails, say on the `/register` page, the URL changes back to `/users`.

I want the URL to stay at `/register` when validation fails. How would I do this?

Comment: So, I basically had the same problem as you did and got to the same solution. The problem with this solution is that setting a "after_sign_up_path_for(resource)" no longer works. Did you encounter this same problem, and do you know the answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Balls. Again I figure it out moments after posting by--wouldn't you know it?--reading.

Looking at [How to change the login and signup urls in devise plugin Rails3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180295/how-to-change-the-login-and-signup-urls-in-devise-plugin-rails3) and https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes again, I now have this:

```
# authentication routing
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => 'devise/sessions' }, :skip => [:sessions] do
  get "/login" => "devise/sessions#new", :as => :new_user_session
  post "/login" => "devise/sessions#create", :as => :user_session
  get "/logout" => "devise/sessions#destroy", :as => :destroy_user_session
  get "/register" => "devise/registrations#new", :as => :new_user_registration
  post "/register" => "devise/registrations#create", :as => :user_registration
end
```

Which appears to work as expected.

Comment: Edit: this worked perfectly thanks. Any ideas how I would get this working on a combined login/register page?