# How do I redirect devise sign_in path to a different controller and view? Note:This is before the authentication happens

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

right now in my app users can sign in at `/users/sign_in` . But I would rather have them sign in and sign up at a same place so i have a view already created at `/home/all`. That being said, how do I make sure that every time users go to `/users/sign_in` or `/users/sign_up` they are redirect to `/home/all` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by overriding the devise's default route,

```
 get "/users/sign_up" => 'home#all'
 get "/users/sign_in" => 'home#all'
```

write this to lines in routes file before, **devise_for :users**.

Whenever request comes from /users/sign_up/ or /users/sign_in/, it will be handled by home#all

Comment: ah, it was before `devise_for :users` . Silly . hah, thanks :)

Comment: hi again, i am running into a similar problem again. Lets say if the user enters the wrong password. It then redirects to the layout of `devise/sessions#new` with displaying the error . That being said, in such a case i still want to the show the error on `/home/all`. How do I do it?

Comment: hey there @maximus, any help?

Comment: instead of doing that way you can tell devise to override the url helpers. this one is a similar thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180295/how-to-change-the-login-and-signup-urls-in-devise-plugin-rails3