# How Can I customize rails devise's router?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I can mapping new router rule to devise controller.But When I use `before_filter :authenticate_user!` in a controller. It is still the default devies url to process user login.

how can I do to change the url to a custom one ?

rake routes output:

[ouput in pastbin](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=dipKZa6v)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little unclear.

Do you want to use your own logic for authentication? If it is so, then there is little meaning in using devise, which is supposed to do that for you. However, if you want devise to handle login but want to show a different url in the address bar, like:

`/login` instead of `/users/sign_in` or
`/signup` instead of `/users/sign_up`

then you should check out this [custom devise urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180295/how-to-change-the-login-and-signup-urls-in-devise-plugin-rails3)

Comment: thanks for your answer.I wrote it like the solution you give.But when I use `before_filter :authenticate_user!` in a controller which need login, the explore still redirect to the default url HOST_NAME/users/login.

Comment: can you show the output of 'rake routes' command executed in your terminal at project root?

Comment: the routes seems ok, could you give the content of your routes.rb file?